# Connection or coincidence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

Here are two lemmas, one from number theory and one from finite reflection groups.

1) [HW,p.74] Let p be an odd prime.  Partition the least nonzero residues (mod p)
   into positive (P) and negative (N) halves [so N = -P ].  One can compute the
   Legendre symbol  (a/p)  by multiplying each element in P by  a  and then counting
   up  Neg(aP) =  number of negative residues appearing in  { aP } .

```
The result is   (a/p) = (-1)^Neg(aP) .       [Gauss' lemma].
```

2) [JH,p.14]  Let  W  be a finite reflection group.  Partition the simple roots
   into positive (P) and negative (N) halves [ so N = -P ].  For  w  in  W one can
   compute  sign(w) by applying  w  to each root in P and then counting up
   Neg(wP) = number of negative roots in { wP } .

```
The result is   sign(w) = (-1)^Neg(wP) .
```

Questions:

a) Are there any deeper connections linking these two similar sounding ideas?

b) Do situations similar to the above arise in other areas of math?

References:

[HW]  Hardy and Wright , Introduction to the Theory of Numbers .

[JH]  Humphreys , Reflection groups and Coxeter groups .